Access pipeline activities (SQL Script) in ASA (Azure Synapse Analytics) using python

I am trying to access the sql script node in my pipeline activities using python. The idea is to export sql-script to this node in ASA (Azure Synapse Analytics) using python.
The connection with python to the sqlpool was already successful and could run some sql-code in the sqlpool. However, accessing the pipeline activities is what i am trying to achieve.

Do you want to run SQL script which is in synapse workspace in script activity and could you please provide the code what you have tried?

To export SQL-script from SQL pool to this node in ASA i.e. pipeline activities instead of using python you can follow below approach:
Run <workspaceName>.dev.azuresynapse.net/sqlScripts?api-version=2020-12-01 endpoint from web activity with Get method. Configure web activity as shown below:

You will get SQL scripts and their details in workspace as output of web activity as shown below:

Add script activity on success of web activity, create azure synapse analytics linked service as shown below:

Use above linked service in script activity and add @activity('Web1').output.value[1].properties.content.query dynamic content in query   section, here I am running script 8 which that means that is the second item in value list in the web activity output that's why I am mentioning value[1] , change it according to your requirement.

Debug the pipeline, the query in the SQL script will execute successfully as shown below:

If you want to use python, run the python code in synapse notebook and use notebook activity.

@Ahmed Basiouny Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
"
